# Results filtered out even though the data is there

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Here's my query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?parentOrSpouse
WHERE { 
?resource a dbo:Royalty ; 
rdfs:label ?label ; 
dbo:parent ?parent ; 
dbo:birthDate ?bd ; 
dbo:birthPlace ?bp . 
?bp dbo:isPartOf :England . 
FILTER(?bd < '1900-01-01'^^xsd:dateTime) . 
FILTER(?bd > '1800-01-01'^^xsd:dateTime) . 
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) . 
{ ?resource dbo:parent ?parentOrSpouse } UNION { ?resource dbo:spouse ?parentOrSpouse }
?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace ?psbp .
?psbp dbo:isPartOf :England . 
}
ORDER BY(?bd)
```

This searches for all royals born in England between 1800 and 1900 that have a spouse or parent that is born in England.

[Result](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fresource%20%3FparentOrSpouse%20%23%3Fpsbp%20%23%20%3Fdepiction%20%3Flabel%20%3Fmother%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fresource%20a%20dbo%3ARoyalty%20%3B%20%0D%0Ardfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%3B%20%0D%0Adbo%3Aparent%20%3Fparent%20%3B%20%0D%0Adbo%3AbirthDate%20%3Fbd%20%3B%20%0D%0Adbo%3AbirthPlace%20%3Fbp%20.%20%0D%0A%3Fbp%20dbo%3AisPartOf%20%3AEngland%20.%20%0D%0AFILTER%28%3Fbd%20%3C%20%271900-01-01%27%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%20.%20%0D%0AFILTER%28%3Fbd%20%3E%20%271800-01-01%27%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%20.%20%0D%0AFILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20.%20%0D%0A%7B%20%3Fresource%20dbo%3Aparent%20%3FparentOrSpouse%20%7D%20UNION%20%7B%20%3Fresource%20dbo%3Aspouse%20%3FparentOrSpouse%20%7D%0D%0A%3FparentOrSpouse%20dbo%3AbirthPlace%20%3Fpsbp%20.%0D%0A%3Fpsbp%20dbo%3AisPartOf%20%3AEngland%20.%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%28%3Fbd%29&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

In the result list I get
http://dbpedia.org/page/George_V with http://dbpedia.org/page/Mary_of_Teck listed as a spouse, but not Mary_of_Teck listed while George is clearly born in England.

Why is Mary disappearing? There are a lot of other people disappearing that should clearly be on the list when I look at the data.

Comment: May I ask why you delete your previous question? This is clearly not the idea of Stackoverflow or how could others search for similar questions if everybody deletes the question once the problem was solved...

Comment: Regarding the query, the result looks strange. removing the last two triple patterns return the result. The query can be simplified by `?resource dbo:parent|dbo:spouse ?parentOrSpouse .`

Comment: Using this simplified query `SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?parentOrSpouse ?psbp
WHERE { 
values ?resource {dbr:Mary_of_Teck}
?resource a dbo:Royalty .

?resource dbo:parent|dbo:spouse ?parentOrSpouse .
optional {?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace ?psbp .}
}` shows no birth place for George_V - indeed, there is a birth place in DBpedia.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem: http://dbpedia.org/resource/King_George_V is redirected to http://dbpedia.org/resource/George_V. That's the reason

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?parentOrSpouse
WHERE { 
?resource a dbo:Royalty ; 
rdfs:label ?label ; 
dbo:parent ?parent ; 
dbo:birthDate ?bd ; 
dbo:birthPlace ?bp . 
?bp dbo:isPartOf dbr:England . 
FILTER(?bd < '1900-01-01'^^xsd:dateTime) . 
FILTER(?bd > '1800-01-01'^^xsd:dateTime) . 
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en')) . 
?resource dbo:parent|dbo:spouse/dbo:wikiPageRedirects? ?parentOrSpouse .
?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace ?psbp .
?psbp dbo:isPartOf dbr:England . 
}
ORDER BY(?bd)`

Comment: Hey, thx for the replies. I deleted the other question because the problem was the order of the statements which was completely irrelevant to what I asked.

Comment: Even in your query http://dbpedia.org/page/Queen_Victoria is missing. She's born in 1819 and her father is born in London.

Comment: @AKSW Also, could you maybe explain how the syntax for `/dbo:wikiPageRedirects?` works? What exactly does the `/` do?

Comment: `dbo:parent|dbo:spouse/dbo:wikiPageRedirects?` or to make it more understandable `(dbo:parent|dbo:spouse)/dbo:wikiPageRedirects?` denotes a [property path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths).

Comment: Please carefully look at the data! http://dbpedia.org/resource/Queen_Victoria is not returned because her birth place in the dataset is just http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kensington_Palace which in fact is clearly not part of `dbr:England`, but takes another step in the RDF graph to `dbr:London` via `dbo:location` property

Comment: using `dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England . ` instead of `dbo:birthPlace ?bp . ?bp dbo:isPartOf dbr:England .` would be a workaround for this

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstoon how the query works. Does that mean that `dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England` checks for "birthplace OR birthplace/location ispartof England"? Or do you have to write them separtely? If no, how would I distinguish AND and OR?

`?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England` doesn't seem to work.

If you want you can write an answer to this question and I'll accept it.

Comment: `dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England` means a path in the RDF graph with `dbo:location?` meaning an optional edge on the path. `?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England` doesn't work for me as well because Virtuoso is throwing an exception which means it's a bug in the triple store. Indeed, you can rewrite this with the good old UNION pattern comprising one part with the intermediate `dbo:location` triple pattern, and one without it

Comment: I completely missed the question mark. Thanks a lot for helping me to understand sparql.

Comment: `?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace|dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location/dbo:isPartOf :England . `

This works. For anyone that is reading this in the future.

Comment: @AKSW and solniss -- It would be great if one of you could summarize all the errors/issues and their fixes/solutions as an answer ... because comments don't show up as an answer, and people looking for solutions will generally not look at questions with no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to Mary not showing up is to use `dbo:parent|dbo:spouse/dbo:wikiPageRedirects?`, since George is refered by Mary via a redirect.

The other problem was `dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England` throwing an error that is probably(?) related to a bug in the compiler. Using `?parentOrSpouse dbo:birthPlace|dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location/dbo:isPartOf :England .` instead seems to work fine.

Credit goes to @AKSW.