# SPARQL, dbpedia : Retrieve values of resource linked as property, type person

Tags: database, sparql, dbpedia

I need to retrieve the name of a person's mother, and I have no idea how to do so.

This is the query I'm currently working with:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 


SELECT DISTINCT 
    ?resource ?depiction ?label ?parent ?bd 
WHERE { 
    ?resource a dbo:Royalty ; foaf:depiction ?depiction ; rdfs:label ?label;
    dbo:parent ?parent; dbo:birthDate ?bd; 
    dbo:birthPlace ?bp . ?bp dbo:isPartOf :England . 
    FILTER(
        LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en') && ?bd < '1900-01-01'^^xsd:date)
} 
ORDER BY DESC(?bd)
```

Some of it was given, some of it was added by me.

As you can see I want to retrieve all royals (with Label and depiction) who were born in England before 1900. But I also want to retrieve the name of a person's mother.

`?parent` contains links to the person's parents and I can't seem to figure out how to:

1. retrieve only the mother and
2. How to get her name/label, since this only returns the url.

For example: 
For: `http://dbpedia.org/page/Charlotte_of_Mecklenburg-Strelitz`

`?parent`s are:

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/Princess_Elisabeth_Albertine_of_Saxe-Hildburghausen
```

and

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/Duke_Charles_Louis_Frederick_of_Mecklenburg
```

But I would need :

```
Princess Elisabeth Albertine of Saxe-Hildburghausen
```

Comment: 1) you're doing the same thing like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327523/results-filtered-out-even-though-the-data-is-there), thus I assume it's a homework, maybe you can share knowledge with the other

Comment: 2) you can only query for data that is contained in the dataset, and gender is not contained in DBpedia afaik. You can check for all the available data via opening one of the resources you're interested in in the browser - no gender via a dedicated triple, or at least not always at Gilles-Antoine points out in his link.

Comment: Gender in DBpedia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887558/get-a-gender-of-a-particular-person-in-sparql

Comment: 3) a workaround as suggested in the other question was to use a YAGO type which infact is based in Wikipedia categories. For example, `http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Female109619168` would be something you need here

Comment: By the way, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53327523/results-filtered-out-even-though-the-data-is-there), `dbo:birthPlace ?bp . ?bp dbo:isPartOf :England . ` does not always work. A suggestion was to use a property path `dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf dbr:England`

Comment: add this for the gender stuff: `{?parent foaf:gender "female"@en } union {?parent a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Female109619168>}`

Comment: for the "name" just get the English label of the `?parent` as you also did (or better said copy/pasted) for the `?resource` already

Comment: something like this (might be incomplete): `SELECT distinct ?resource ?label ?bd ?depiction ?parent ?parentLabel
WHERE { 
    ?resource a dbo:Royalty ; foaf:depiction ?depiction ; rdfs:label ?label;
    dbo:parent ?parent; dbo:birthDate ?bd; 
    dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf :England . 
?parent rdfs:label ?parentLabel.
    FILTER(
        LANGMATCHES(LANG(?parentLabel), 'en') && LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), 'en') && ?bd < '1900-01-01'^^xsd:date)
{?parent foaf:gender "female"@en } union {?parent a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Female109619168>}
} ORDER BY DESC(?bd)`

Comment: @AKSW thank you so much, this worked like a charm ! I'm very new to this, so this was a big help to understand the overall syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @AKSW, a possibly-incomplete query (formatted here for improved clarity) --

```
PREFIX  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX   rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX  foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX  yago:  <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX      :  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 

SELECT DISTINCT 
  ?resource
  ?label
  ?bd
  ?depiction
  ?parent
  ?parentLabel 
WHERE
  { ?resource  a                                          dbo:Royalty ; 
               foaf:depiction                             ?depiction ; 
               rdfs:label                                 ?label ; 
               dbo:parent                                 ?parent ; 
               dbo:birthDate                              ?bd ; 
               dbo:birthPlace/dbo:location?/dbo:isPartOf  :England . 
    ?parent    rdfs:label                                 ?parentLabel . 
    FILTER     (  LANGMATCHES ( LANG ( ?parentLabel ), 'en' )
               && LANGMATCHES ( LANG ( ?label ), 'en' )
               && ?bd < '1900-01-01'^^xsd:date
               )
    { ?parent  foaf:gender                                "female"@en } 
    UNION 
    { ?parent  a                                          yago:Female109619168 } 
  } 
ORDER BY DESC(?bd)
```